# Linux VFS (virtual filesystem)

Tags: linux, git, linux-kernel

Weird question, but still. Git is content-addressable filesystem.

Is it possible to mount git repository into VFS?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting from the Linux kernel in this context.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! This question is a bit unclear and too broad.  What exactly are you looking for? When you say "VFS" what exactly are you imagining? Does this well known "VFSForGit" project meet your need: https://github.com/microsoft/VFSForGit ? This question could be improved by clarifying exactly what you want and how you'd expect git mounted as a VFS would behave. Specifying a particular use case and what you're trying to achieve would help too. But to jump ahead, I think what you're asking is certainly possible but without more details it's hard to give a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you might be looking for is GVFS: Git Virtual File System.

### Linux

I see your question is tagged linux, and am afraid I'm not familiar with a VFS on Linux.

### Windows

In case anyone, just like me, comes across this looking for a git VFS for Windows:
Microsoft created a VFS system for Git: [VFSForGit](https://github.com/microsoft/VFSForGit), which is now archived. The development moved to [scalar](https://github.com/microsoft/scalar), and Scalar has been moved to [microsoft-git](https://github.com/microsoft/git).

Each of these repos contains instructions on how to get started.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to mount a Git repository into VFS using tools such as Git Virtual File System (GVFS) or Git-Fuse.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).